# Magento 2 : How to add Translate Code in JavaScript code in PHTML file?

Tags: magento2, javascript, translate, i18n

I am trying to add translate code `<?= __('This field is required') ?>` in the Magento file using JavaScript but it is not working plz help me.

```
if(response.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">'<?php __('This field is required') ?>'</span>';
    return false;
}
```

Are any quotes missing or not calling PHP correctly inside JavaScript quotes?

Comment: is this is pure js file or phtml?

Comment: @RizwanKhan phml file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require(['mage/translate'], function($t)
        {
             
             $t("Your Message Which Need to translate.");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is it not possible to add in my code phtml file.........without adding seperate function

Comment: Yes you can added this code into your phtml file it self. but yes "require" code is necessary.

Comment: my code is working fine without adding php....after adding php only not working.... why require is necessary it is normal php insertion in javascript right ..this is phtml file

Comment: the javascript is required to added translation object over there, then and then it will translate your string.

Comment: anyhow my code is working after changing single quotes to double quotes in php tag